# rollover android

Tags: android, rollover

I want to make a rollover with android.
I saw that it is necesarry to write a XML like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/verde" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rojo" />    
</selector>
```

I saved it with the name button.xml.
I don't know in which folder save it.

Then I tried to used the reference in my layout.xml
I change the background attribute for my button in my layout.xml from 
    `android:background="@drawable/red"`
and use the
    `android:background="@drawable/button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `button.xml` in the folder `res/drawable` if it's applicable for all screen sizes/devices, otherwise put it in the folder with the appropriate qualifier suffix (e.g. `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi` etc).

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) (http://developer.android.com) for a full example, and explanation of other states you could include.